# How to create an object positioning macro for Corel X5?

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I have stacked objects brought on my document (dragged from folder directly, and positioned manually in place where the first object should be). The quantity of the objects varies, so I need code that takes that into account. As a result, the objects should be positioned so that the distance between each object would be 30mm horizontally. The vertical position mustn’t change. The position of one of the objects (last or first of the stack) should stay put. I know how to do this with just using actions, but the problem is the amount of the objects used. An error occurs when the quantities don’t match.
Do I need to use conditional sentences? How do I define the Shapes etc.?
This is how I recorded the actions: First I selected the top object and moved it 30 mm horizontally. Then I added the next object on top of the stack to the existing selection. Then I moved the selected objects 30mm. And again I chose the new object on top of the stack to the selection and performed the movement. I did this until the stacks last object was in its original place alone. In this case 8 objects were used. Here’s the code that were created by using actions:

```
Sub positioning()
    ' Recorded 16.2.2015
    ActiveLayer.Shapes(1).Move 1.181102, 0#
    ActiveDocument.CreateShapeRangeFromArray(ActiveLayer.Shapes(2), ActiveLayer.Shapes(1)).Move 1.181102, 0#
    ActiveLayer.Shapes(3).AddToSelection
    ActiveSelection.Move 1.181102, 0#
    ActiveLayer.Shapes(4).AddToSelection
    ActiveSelection.Move 1.181102, 0#
    ActiveLayer.Shapes(5).AddToSelection
    ActiveSelection.Move 1.181102, 0#
    ActiveLayer.Shapes(6).AddToSelection
    ActiveSelection.Move 1.181102, 0#
    ActiveLayer.Shapes(7).AddToSelection
    ActiveSelection.Move 1.181102, 0#
End Sub
```

I have googled and read about VBA somewhat a lot but couldn’t find simple enough help for this kind of case. I would appreciate if someone thought or showed how to program this, would be a huge help to me!

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
Set sr = ActivePage.SelectableShapes.All
For i = 1 to sr.count
  sr(i).move (1.181102 * i), 0#
Next i
```

and, of course, you should place each `sr(i)` on position reference first :)
like this:

```
sr(i).positionX = 0
sr(i).positionY = 0
```